# How do I convert Empirical Baysean Krigged 3D Data/Multidimensional Raster into a cube or vertical diagram?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, 3d-analyst

I'm currently working on a project that has resulted in me creating a 3D Empirical Baysean Kriging (EBK) model, which represents various points of data in the soil. However, this has only resulted in a series of rasters that can be visualized on a slider, and I would like to visualize all of them at once in either the form of a cube (ideally slice-able) or in a fence diagram.

I tried converting it to a multidimensional raster, but even then I couldn't get it them to appear in a fence diagram, and getting them to extrude upwards to make a cube was also impossible since they were just projected on the surface level.